# compile error using visual studio for c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I compile below code in visual studio community 2017, there are many errors. Can you tell how to solve this problem?

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class TrainComposition
{
    std::vector<int> wagons;

    public:   

    void attachWagonFromLeft(int wagonId)
    {
      wagons.insert(wagons.begin(), wagonId);
      std::cout << "attach wagon from left, id is:" << wagonId << '\n';
    }
 ....
```

> 1>c:\users\wanglei\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(6): error C2039: 'vector': is not a member of 'std'
>   1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\iostream(13): note: see declaration of 'std'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the vector library at the top of your file with the rest of your include statements.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class TrainComposition
{
    std::vector<int> wagons;

    public:   

    void attachWagonFromLeft(int wagonId)
    {
      wagons.insert(wagons.begin(), wagonId);
      std::cout << "attach wagon from left, id is:" << wagonId << '\n';
    }
```